# Reversing a Circular double linked list in C language

Tags: c, reverse, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

```
struct node *reverse()
{
    if(tail == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty");
        return tail;
    }
    struct node *nxt,*prv,*p = tail->next;
    do
    {
        nxt = p->next;
        prv = p->prev;
        p->next = prv;
        p->prev = nxt;
        p = nxt;
    }while(p!=tail->next);
    tail = nxt;
    return tail;
};
```

the input :`nodea,nodeb,nodec`
the output:`nodea,nodeb`
expected Ouput:`nodec,nodeb,nodea`
i dont know whats wrong with my code...anyone can help me?

Comment: What is the exercise, to actually reverse the list or just to print it in reverse? If actually reversing, reverse "in place" or create a reversed copy of the list?

Comment: print it in reverse

Comment: Then just iterate from the end to the beginning, and print each node. No need to actually reverse the list itself.

Comment: hmmm....shouldn't I have to change its position first so that when it is printed it will come out in reverse?

Comment: To print the list normally you loop from the beginning to the end, right? Think about what happens if you loop from the end to the beginning instead... No need to modify the list at all.

Comment: If it is doubly linked, then why reverse it? You can just traverse it with the other pointer.

Comment: `p = tail->next` hmm... that looks strange... `tail->next` would normally be NULL